# gitolite-config with user-name in branch pattern possible?

Tags: gitolite

I want to configure something like

```
@developer  = user1 user2
repo test
    C   ^dev/$user- = @developer
    RW+ ^dev/$user- = @developer
```

So that each user in @developer has complete control over all corresponding branches under dev/ with the user-name in it.

Is there a way to make something like that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
@developer = user1 user2
repo test
    RW+ dev/USER/ = @developer
```

(There might be some syntax errors in that snippet, I did not test it.)

See https://gitolite.com/gitolite/user.html#personal-branches for details.